# The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the greater than operator

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using the latest NuGet package of Fluent NHibernate (1.3.0.727), but I'm still experiencing an issue I thought was fixed in NHibernate 3.2 (the latest Fluent uses NHib 3.3). The database is SQL Server 2008 on Azure.

When I run a query that compares a .NET **TimeSpan** with a sql **Time** field, it throws the following exception:

> The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the greater than operator.

Here's a sample query:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
List<Message> messages = messageRepo.FilterBy(m => m.SendTime > ts).ToList();
```

Here's my Message class snippet:

```
public class Message
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public virtual TimeSpan? SendTime { get; set; }}
}
```

And here's the relevant mapping details:

```
public class MessageMap : ClassMap<Message>
{
    public MessageMap()
    {
        Table("Message");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("MessageID");
        Map(x => x.SendTime).Column("SendTime").CustomType("TimeAsTimeSpan");
    }
}
```

I've searched all over and tried everything I can find or think of. Maybe I'm just missing something obvious? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that Fluent's MsSql2008 configuration is setting the NHibernate database driver to one that doesn't handle the TimeAsTimeSpan properly. Manually setting the Driver to Sql2008ClientDriver fixes the problem. See line 4 below:

```
var rawConfig = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(
        MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(x => x.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ConnectionString"))
            .Driver("NHibernate.Driver.Sql2008ClientDriver")
    )
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SiteUserMap>())
    .BuildConfiguration();
```

Comment: Nearly 9 years later, and this was the solution to my problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

TimeSpan can hold several days, so it's compatible with DateTime, not Time. Time only contains the time of day. So I think you should not use the DataType attribute for your property - at least not DataType.Time.